# Libraries are not loading while creating zend project using command line toll

Tags: php, zend-framework

Using the CLI tool i am creating the Zend Skeleton. But didn't get any libraries into the libraries folder.so please let me know can i import the libraries using the CLI tool or not? if yes please suggest me how to do? else please suggest me how to install the zend properly in my windows 8 system.

Comment: -1 Not a real question. [**Learn how to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you very much for advise.if you understood what i am asking please help me

Comment: We don't understand what you are asking. You need to write a better question. Follow @cept0's link, read, learn and update your question

Comment: Please let me know how to create the zend project in my local windows  system pls.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI tool that your using just creates project skeleton, default routes and controllers. It doesn't add any libraries to the library folder.

You'll have to manually download the libraries and put the Zend Folder of the downloaded libraries into the library folder of your project. You can download the minimum distribution using the link blow. This distribution only contains libraries and the CLI tool.

[ZF Minimal Package](http://www.zend.com/en/download/808)

Comment: Thank you very  much Jay Bhatt.But i here that in zend2 it's possible is it correct or not?

Comment: @MurthyMuddu It will just copy this to your project folder https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication and this doesn't contain any libraries.

Comment: Yes i have downloaded and copied it into to the xampp/htdoccs but while browsing the url it shows me white page.And i am using zend 1.12.3

Comment: @MurthyMuddu You need to create a virtual host and enable errors in your php.ini referrer this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-zend-framework-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

Comment: Please let me know the correct process of creating the zend project?

Comment: @MurthyMuddu The process is long to describe here but read this http://jeremykendall.net/2010/04/17/from-zero-to-zend-framework-project-in-10-minutes/ and this http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Comment: yes i have added the virtulal host also but it again comes a white page only. I am using the windows system

Comment: @MurthyMuddu enable error reporting in your php.ini. http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/qt/php_error_reporting.htm

Comment: Yes i too know that i was trying to install the zend in different methods but using the CLI tool i am getting the problem like libraries are not automatically loading into the project folder.

Comment: I did that too also but still shows me a white page only.

Comment: @MurthyMuddu Have you placed libraries/Zend folder in your library folder?

Comment: Sorry I can't post many comments here and you don't have enough reputation to chat. But post your project skeleton and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Yes i did it. my project folder is zendgit->library->Zend-> and libraries like ACL,Amf,etc.,